# Report and reportviewer control not in same project how can i access report

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, report, reportviewer

I have `reportviewer` in winforms project. In the second project i got report and its datasource.
How correctly access the report from `winform`'s project?

What i did so far in win forms project:

```
var pathToReport= @"C:\Users\Term\Report Project1\Raport1.rdl";
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = pathToReport;
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Once i run with this i got error:

```
a data source instance has not been suplied for the data soruce 'DataSet1'
```

In the project where report is located there is that dataset therefore somehow i could point to it? Look:

[image]

I found `ReportDataSource()` but i do not see any option to give path to dataset located in second project.

Comment: Are you using a SQL Server?  You can put the rdlc file in the SQL Server Report Manager so you can access the file as a webpage.  RDLC is http format.

Comment: @jdweng I want to show the report in windows forms application

Comment: You could add a WebBrowser to form and then  webBrowser1.Navigate("URL")

Comment: @jdweng i've installed reporting services by your advice and loaded report. Nevertheless when i click on it it says: The report server cannot process the report. The reference for the shared dataset 'DataSet1' is not valid. (rsInvalidDataSetReference)

Comment: You can open the RDLC in notepad to help debug.  The SQL Query is in tags "Command_Text".  I'm not sure if this error is due to a parameter missing in the query or the permissions of the database is wrong.  You can do a search in Notepad for DataSet1 to find out if it is a parameter (may be set to null) or it is a table in the database.

Comment: @jdweng i see what you mean generally : i can install SSRS - create reports there on SQL SERVER and access them from visual studio to provide report into reportviewer on form. Can you confirm? Morover does SSRS and report builder are embded in any SQL SERVER version (asking as if i go this way i need to know for my client to buy...

Comment: The report is a URL so you can access from any application that accepts a URL.  Not sure how the Manager is bundled.  With SQL Server there is an Express Version (free, restirctions) and the Full Version.  I have full version so I'm not sure what comes with express.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @jdweng hmm i see, but going back to my initial question, is there any way to point to existing datasource for report? I think that would be just enough for me without sql server part

Comment: Parameters for a URL are at the end with a question mark followed by the parameters separated by a semicolon and an ampersand.

Comment: Try step 4 at following : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a72401/rdlc-report-generation-using-dataset/

Comment: @jdweng i know all of this, this is not answering my initial question. How to access already created report from windows foirms project to the other project where report is located with itsa dataset

Comment: A Database MDF file is usually attached to a server (except localDb).So if the database is attached to the server the connection is to a server.  LocalDb should really not be used  when more than one user needs access to the data.  If you want to use the form from another project then create a Class project and then add form to class project.  The class project will create a dll which you can add as a reference from other projects.

Answer (score 0):

you can try load report definition from dll file of second project, then add a datasource to report definition, for this, you need a reference to second project:

```
            System.Reflection.Assembly Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom ("SecondProject.dll" );
            System.IO.Stream Stream = Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream ( "SecondProject.Report1.rdlc" );

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition ( Stream );
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear ( );
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add ( new ReportDataSource ( "DataSet1" , SecondProject.MyDataSource ) );
```